Inferring the generic types of an Angular test utility function
The function I created takes an optional array of objects with a name and value property. I would like to have the value property infer or pass the type of what the value is. I can get it to work properly with one object, but when there is more than one it keeps the type of the first object only. Here is the utility function:
import { Type } from '@angular/core'
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'

export type InputSignal = Record<string, any>

export type AdditionalProvider<K, V> = { name: K; value: Type<V> }

export type SetupTestOptions<K extends string, V> = {
  setInput?: InputSignal
  additionalProviders?: AdditionalProvider<K, V>[]
}

export function setupTest<T extends object, K extends string, V>(
  Component: Type<T>,
  options: SetupTestOptions<K, V> = {}
) {
  const fixture: ComponentFixture<T> = TestBed.createComponent(Component)
  const component: T = fixture.componentInstance

  if (options.setInput) {
    Object.keys(options.setInput).forEach(key => {
      if (!options.setInput) return
      fixture.componentRef.setInput(key, options.setInput[key])
    })
  }

  const providers = <Record<K, V>>{}

  if (options.additionalProviders) {
    options.additionalProviders.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
      providers[name] = TestBed.inject(value) <-- here is where I would like the types to be inferred.
    })
  }

  fixture.detectChanges()

  return { fixture, component, ...providers }
}


Here is an example of how it is used:
it('should route to the dashboard/home route if projectId is null', async () => {
    const { fixture, component, location, ngZone, router } = setupTest(DashboardComponent, {
      additionalProviders: [
        { name: 'location', value: Location },
        { name: 'router', value: Router },
        { name: 'ngZone', value: NgZone }
      ]
    })

    ngZone.run(() => {
      router.initialNavigation()
      component.ngOnInit()
    })

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/dashboard/home')
    })
  })

I tried many variations of having type V extend different Angular utility types and even explicitly added the types that I want in this use case. The closest I can get is to have a union of the 3 different services (Location | Router | NgZone) but that defeats the purpose because then I have to cast all of the types when using them. I would like TypeScript to infer the correct type based on the value and pass that type to the name I am destructuring in the example.

Dont get bogged down by using types in test cases, just use as any at the end of the object and start testing.

That is what I am doing currently.  Just hoping that someone can figure this out so I can get the autocomplete for the services that are being used.

I agree with Naren, but I also think the type inference makes tests easier to write and maintain, so here's a solution:
import { Type } from '@angular/core'
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'

export type InputSignal = Record<string, any>

export type AdditionalProviders = { name: string, value: Type<any> }[];

type GetType<T> = T extends { value: Type<infer V> } ? V : never;

type ProvidersReturnType<TP extends AdditionalProviders> = {
    [TK in TP[number]['name']]: GetType<Extract<TP[number], { name: TK }>>;
}

export type SetupTestOptions<TProviders extends AdditionalProviders> = {
    setInput?: InputSignal;
    additionalProviders?: TProviders;
}

export function setupTest<T extends object, const TP extends AdditionalProviders>(
    Component: Type<T>,
    options: SetupTestOptions<TP> = {}
) {
    const fixture: ComponentFixture<T> = TestBed.createComponent(Component)
    const component: T = fixture.componentInstance

    if (options.setInput) {
        Object.keys(options.setInput).forEach(key => {
            if (!options.setInput) return
            fixture.componentRef.setInput(key, options.setInput[key])
        })
    }

    const providers: ProvidersReturnType<TP> = {} as any;

    if (options.additionalProviders) {
        options.additionalProviders.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
            (providers as any)[name] = TestBed.inject(value); // < --here is where I would like the types to be inferred.
        });
    }

    fixture.detectChanges()
    return { fixture, component, ...providers }
}

Typescript Playground


Just tried this and it works!!

Don't get bogged down by using types in test cases, just use as any at the end of the object and start testing. If an interface requires 10 fields, but you only need 1 field to test the function, is it practical to create the remaining 9 fields when they are not needed?
This example should highlights the insignificance of strict typing in testing.
  it('should route to the dashboard/home route if projectId is null', async () => {
    const { fixture, component, location, ngZone, router } = setupTest(DashboardComponent, {
      additionalProviders: [
        { name: 'location', value: Location },
        { name: 'router', value: Router },
        { name: 'ngZone', value: NgZone }
      ]
    } as any)

    ngZone.run(() => {
      router.initialNavigation()
      component.ngOnInit()
    })

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/dashboard/home')
    })
  })

